# Getting Error When Trying to Render Page with React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

In my App.js, I am calling a custom React Hook. When I try to navigate to the page with the custom React Hook, it throws an error:

```
Error: WithAuth(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

I know that this seems self-explanatory, but I am new to React. I am trying to redirect the user to the login page if they are not logged in when they try to navigate to the Dashboard page. I know that somewhere I need to return null, but I can't figure out where. Any help would be awesome. Thank you.

**App.js**

```
import WithAuth from "./hoc/withAuth";
const App = (props) => {
    return (
        <Route
          path="/dashboard"
          render={() => (
            <WithAuth>
              <MainLayout>
                <Dashboard />
              </MainLayout>
            </WithAuth>
          )}
        />
    );
};
```

**withAuth.js**

```
import { useAuth } from "./../customHooks";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const WithAuth = (props) => useAuth(props) && props.children;

export default withRouter(WithAuth);
```

**useAuth.js**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const mapState = ({ user }) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser,
});

const useAuth = (props) => {
  const { currentUser } = useSelector(mapState);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!currentUser) {
      props.history.push("/login");
    }
  }, [currentUser]);

  return currentUser;
};

export default useAuth;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your `useAuth(props)` is returning a falsey value and thus no children are returned.

```
const WithAuth = (props) => useAuth(props) && props.children;
```

You should return null to indicate to React that nothing should be rendered.

```
const WithAuth = (props) => useAuth(props) ? props.children : null;
```

[Preventing Component from Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering)

Generally booleans are ignored in the returned JSX ***except*** when it's the return value, it must be either a valid JSX node or null.

Comment: Yeah, that did it. I appreciate it, man. Thanks for the additional info, too!

Comment: @Matt I didn't call it out, but name prefix `"with"` is typically reserved for Higher Order Components. See `withRouter` for example, it's a function that consumes a component and returns a new component. The `WithAuth` name threw me for a moment when it consumed props. It's functioning more as a "wrapper" than a HOC.